# How to use Jest with jsdom to test console.log?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm just getting set up with Jest and I've successfully written unit tests that test the DOM. I have a [library](https://github.com/qodesmith/typer) that types things on the screen, so I'm able to test just fine. In some cases, instead of throwing an error, my library will spit out a `console.warn` or `console.log`. Is it possible to use Jest to test that these console messages are happening?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can set console.log to by a spy like this:

```
global.console = {
  warn: jest.fn(),
  log: jest.fn()
}

// run your code

expect(global.console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
```

As your test file runs in a separate thread you don't need to reset `console` to the original methods

Comment: if you want the console to still work, and be spied on, use `sinon.spy`

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want test a function like this by printing a message:

```
function sayHello () { console.log('Hello!') }
```

You can use `jest.spyOn` function to change how `console.log` function behaves.

```js
function sayHello () { console.log('Hello!') };
describe('logging "Hello"', () => {
  const log = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'log');
  sayHello();
  it('should print to console', () => {
    expect(log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello!');
  });
});
```

**OR** you can redefine `console` object and add a key with `jest.fn` value, like this:

```
describe('sayHello prints "Hello!"', () => {
  const log = jest.fn()
  global.console = { log }
  sayHello()
  expect(log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello!')
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. `jest.spyOn(global.console, 'log')` is much better than overriding then default logging functionality.

Comment: This is the best way to approach this today. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Can't get this to work if sayHello() is part of another component. Any ideas?